# How to use SCTP?

Tags: sctp

For my thesis I am studying and showing a new communication protocol which our teacher didn't talk to us about. This is SCTP.

Now I am writing my thesis, explaining the protocol and underlining the differences between SCTP and TCP. Anyway, I'm asked to realized a little application client-server too in Linux Ubuntu environment. Can anyone link some stuff concerning SCTP primitives or a simple example of client-server SCTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend you buy a copy of the book *Unix Network Programming: The Sockets Networking API* by Stevens,Fenner,& Rudoff. It has several chapters on SCTP sockets and how to use them. Also, check out *SCTP: A reference guide*.

Answer (score 3):

The best place is [RFC 3286](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3286.txt) for introduction and [RFC 4960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960) for details. It'll clear all of your doubts regarding SCTP. Just to find SCTP vs TCP, you can go through only RFC 3286. It's small and right to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I could give you some questions as guidelines.

1. What sctp can do but tcp can not do?
2. If both of sctp and tcp can do, why prefer sctp or tcp?
3. Why sctp not popular? tcp popular?
4. Has sctp better performance?

About client/server examples you can find in the book as Mr X recommended.
Using benchmark is helpful.